# Max Noether's theorem for algebraic surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, algebraic-surfaces

The well-known Max Noether's theorem for curves [see Arbarello-Cornalba-Griffiths-Harris *Geometry of Algebraic Curves* vol.1, p. 117] states that, if a smooth curve $C$ is non-hyperelliptic, then the symmetrization homomorphisms $$\mathrm{Sym}^n \, H^0(C, \, K_C) \longrightarrow H^0(C, \, nK_C)$$
are surjective for $n \geq 1$.

> **Q.** Are there generalization of this result for algebraic surfaces? In other words, if $S$ is a smooth surface, what can we say about the surjectivity of the homomorphisms $$\mathrm{Sym}^n \, H^0(S, \, \Omega_S^1) \longrightarrow H^0(S, \, \mathrm{Sym}^n \, \Omega^1_S)?$$

**Edit.** I'm glad to make some additional assumptions. For instance, what  can we say if $\Omega_S$ is globally generated?

Comment: Probably not much, in general. There are many surfaces with ample cotangent bundle, but $q=0$, so the map is not surjective for $n>1$ (e.g., fake projective planes). Perhaps if you add more hypotheses, like the cotangent bundle being globally generated or something like that, you might say something..

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm ready to assume that $\Omega_S$ is generated by global sections. Are there results in that case?

Comment: Your question is equivalent to asking whether the section ring of $O(1)$ on the projectivization of the cotangent bundle is generated in degree 1. There are theorems that guarantee that this holds, e.g., if you know that a lot of the right cohomology groups vanish.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. I am rather looking for results (if they exist) of the form "for such and such surface, the map is surjective".